# Wiping a System 76 laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, 15.10

Its been a while since I've wiped a laptop with and wanted to make sure there was no reason why this should be an issue.  Picked up a used system 76 laptop that has ubuntu 15 preinstalled.  Planning on wiping it for security reasons with a ubuntu boot usb.

While I don't think this should be an issue, I just wanted to check with the community first.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Recreating the partition table and then letting Ubuntu create new partitions (either during installation or manually via `fdisk` or a GUI partition manager like GParted) may not be forensically secure, but if you perform a secure wipe of the entire drive then do the above, you should be fine for anyone with fewer resources than the CIA or NSA.